# PHP Active Record Find Rows Between 2 Dates

Tags: php, activerecord

I have just started to use php active record to select rows between 2 dates, it seems to work on some tests but on some it fails, this is what i have so far

```
$to = $_POST['to'];

$from = $_POST['from'];

$visitors = Visitors::find('all', array('conditions' => "visitdate >= '$from' AND visitdate <= '$to'"));
```

is there a between clause available?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to designate `visitdate` as a `DATE` in order to compare the strings.

```
$visitors = Visitors::find('all', array('conditions' => "DATE(visitdate) BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'"));
```

More here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Comment: Do you mind accepting the answer if it is indeed the correct solution to your question?